# how to determine the current and future electron version(s) of vscode at extention build time

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I'm collaborating on a vscode extension that uses a native module (@serialport) which needs to be included / pre-compiled for each platform/electron-version combination.

if we only include the current versions, it frequently breaks when vscode updates the electron version. some platforms can natively re-compile , other can only after a (very) lengthy install of rather-complex toolchains that IMO should not be required for end-users.

***So we want to include the relevant prebuilds,

and for that we need to look ahead in time ...***

I'm looking for a reliable method to determine the electron versions used by vscode

- current version
- and the future (insider) version
- in addition it may be good to include a prior version to allow for backward compatibility

I have found that [master/.yarnrc](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/.yarnrc) has the current ( or next imminent) version

- today it is 4.2.7
- vscode current release uses 4.2.5
- prior versions can be read from the version history
  [master/.yarnrc](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commits/master/.yarnrc)
- but what about the future / insider version ?
  what is a good method/location to determine that programmatically ?, i.e. Which branch has the insiders version ?

***Probable answer based on below hints and some more probing :***

- next version is in master `..microsoft/vscode/blob/.yarnrc`
- version 1.36.1 is in `..microsoft/vscode/blob/1.36.1/.yarnrc`
- version x.y.z is in `..microsoft/vscode/blob/x.y.z/.yarnrc`

which only leaves the in-between versions/tags to be discovered.

### intended approach:

- during the build collect the relevant electron versions, ie "3.1.8","4.2.5","6.0.0-beta.0"
- determine the ABI used by these versions using node-abi
  `var getAbi = require('node-abi').getAbi;getAbi('$version','electron')`
- use prebuild-install to download the relevant native prebuilds bindings, and include these as part of the extension
  `.\node_modules\.bin\prebuild-install.cmd --runtime electron --target $version --arch $arch --platform $platform --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@`
- copy the bindings files for all ABI-arch-platform combinations to a folder, and include that in the vscode extension package
- at load time , determine the ABI version of the running instance of vscode/electron, and dynamically load the module from the ABI/platform folder

alternative / additional approach:

- as a last ditch effort the code could try a just-in-time download of the pre-build binding file for the current platform, but this might run into permissions/malware scanner problems as that is essentially downloading executable code from an external github repro.

current script code to download the bindings:
https://github.com/Josverl/pymakr-vsc/blob/fix/SerialMultiPlatform/scripts/mp-download.ps1

Comment: "but what about the future / insider version" - I don't follow, the latest master branch should be in sync with Insider's builds?

Comment: let me rephrase that part of the question to : 
'Which branch is the insiders version ?'

Comment: Insiders is built from master.

Comment: okay, so reverse logic then indicates that:

- next version is in master `..microsoft/vscode/blob/.yarnrc`  
- version 1.36.1 is in `..microsoft/vscode/blob/1.36.1/.yarnrc`  
- version x.y.z is in `..microsoft/vscode/blob/x.y.z/.yarnrc`  

which only leaves the in-between tags to be discovered.

Comment: highly related question to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59142561/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so reverse logic then indicates that:

- next version is in master `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/master/.yarnrc`
- version 1.36.1 is in `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/1.36.1/.yarnrc`
- version x.y.z is in `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/x.y.z/.yarnrc`

which only leaves the in-between versions/tags to be discovered.