# Where can I find a table with VSCode versions matched with Electron versions?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I am building a native Node.js addon for Electron (VSCode, actually). Electron has different versions and some of them have different `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` parameter, and the addon must be built for every such parameter.

So is there such a table, like [this one](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) for Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## Edit: There is a more updated version:

#### [How can I find which version of node ships with each version of Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824668/how-can-i-find-which-version-of-node-ships-with-each-version-of-visual-studio-co)

---

This repository, but it's outdated:

https://github.com/Sneezry/vscode-version-watcher

| VS Code | Electron | Node | Chrome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Latest | 12.0.9 | 14.16.0 | 89.0.4389.128 |
| 1.57.0 | 12.0.9 | 14.16.0 | 89.0.4389.128 |
| 1.56.2 | 12.0.4 | 14.16.0 | 89.0.4389.114 |
| 1.56.1 | 12.0.4 | 14.16.0 | 89.0.4389.114 |
| 1.56.0 | 12.0.4 | 14.16.0 | 89.0.4389.114 |
| 1.55.2 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.55.1 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.55.0 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.54.3 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.54.2 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.999.0 | 3.1.8 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.54.1 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.54.0 | 11.3.0 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.53.2 | 11.2.1 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.53.1 | 11.2.1 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.53.0 | 11.2.1 | 12.18.3 | 87.0.4280.141 |
| 1.52.1 | 9.3.5 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.52.0 | 9.3.5 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.51.1 | 9.3.3 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.51.0 | 9.3.3 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.50.1 | 9.2.1 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.50.0 | 9.2.1 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.49.3 | 9.2.1 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.49.2 | 9.2.1 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.49.1 | 9.2.1 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.49.0 | 9.2.1 | 12.14.1 | 83.0.4103.122 |
| 1.48.2 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.48.1 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.48.0 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.47.3 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.47.2 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.47.1 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.47.0 | 7.3.2 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.46.1 | 7.3.1 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.19.3 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.46.0 | 7.3.1 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.45.1 | 7.2.4 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.45.0 | 7.2.4 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.44.2 | 7.1.11 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.44.1 | 7.1.11 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.44.0 | 7.1.11 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.43.2 | 7.1.11 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.43.1 | 7.1.11 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.43.0 | 7.1.11 | 12.8.1 | 78.0.3904.130 |
| 1.42.1 | 6.1.6 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.42.0 | 6.1.6 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.41.1 | 6.1.5 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.41.0 | 6.1.5 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.40.2 | 6.1.5 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.40.1 | 6.1.2 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.40.0 | 6.1.2 | 12.4.0 | 76.0.3809.146 |
| 1.39.2 | 4.2.10 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.39.1 | 4.2.10 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.39.0 | 4.2.10 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.38.1 | 4.2.10 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.38.0 | 4.2.10 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.37.1 | 4.2.7 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.37.0 | 4.2.7 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.36.1 | 4.2.5 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.36.0 | 4.2.5 | 10.11.0 | 69.0.3497.128 |
| 1.35.1 | 3.1.8 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.35.0 | 3.1.8 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.34.0 | 3.1.8 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.33.1 | 3.1.6 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.33.0 | 3.1.6 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.32.3 | 3.1.6 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.32.2 | 3.1.6 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.32.1 | 3.1.3 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.32.0 | 3.1.3 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.31.1 | 3.1.2 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.31.0 | 3.1.2 | 10.2.0 | 66.0.3359.181 |
| 1.30.2 | 2.0.12 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.30.1 | 2.0.12 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.30.0 | 2.0.12 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.29.1 | 2.0.12 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.29.0 | 2.0.12 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.28.2 | 2.0.9 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.28.1 | 2.0.9 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.28.0 | 2.0.9 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.27.2 | 2.0.7 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.27.1 | 2.0.7 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.27.0 | 2.0.7 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.26.1 | 2.0.5 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.26.0 | 2.0.5 | 8.9.3 | 61.0.3163.100 |
| 1.25.1 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.25.0 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.24.1 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.24.0 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.23.1 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.23.0 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.22.2 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.22.1 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.22.0 | 1.7.12 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.21.1 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.21.0 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.20.1 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.20.0 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.19.2 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.19.1 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.19.0 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.18.1 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.18.0 | 1.7.9 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.17.2 | 1.7.7 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.17.1 | 1.7.7 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.17.0 | 1.7.7 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.16.1 | 1.7.3 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.16.0 | 1.7.3 | 7.9.0 | 58.0.3029.110 |
| 1.15.1 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.15.0 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.14.2 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.14.1 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.14.0 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.13.1 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.13.0 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.12.2 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.12.1 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.12.0 | 1.6.6 | 7.4.0 | 56.0.2924.87 |
| 1.11.2 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.11.1 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.11.0 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.10.2 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.10.1 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.10.0 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.9.1 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.9.0 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.8.1 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.8.0 | 1.4.6 | 6.5.0 | 53.0.2785.143 |
| 1.7.2 | 1.3.8 | 6.5.0 | 52.0.2743.82 |
| 1.7.1 | 1.3.8 | 6.5.0 | 52.0.2743.82 |
| 1.7.0 | 1.3.8 | 6.5.0 | 52.0.2743.82 |
| 1.6.1 | 1.3.7 | 6.5.0 | 52.0.2743.82 |
| 1.6.0 | 1.3.7 | 6.5.0 | 52.0.2743.82 |
| 1.5.3 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.5.2 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.5.1 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.5.0 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.4.0 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.3.1 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.3.0 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.2.1 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.2.0 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.1.1 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.1.0 | 0.37.6 | 5.10.0 | 49.0.2623.75 |
| 1.0.0 | 0.35.6 | 4.1.1 | 45.0.2454.85 |

Answer (score -1):

In case you're building the addon in github actions, I've developed an action that might be of use:

[VSCode Version Matrix github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/vscode-version-matrix) ([source code](https://github.com/EcksDy/vscode-version-matrix)).

This also might be handy for people who are testing their VSCode extensions in Github Actions.

Comment: What is "this"? Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it, instead of linking to external ressources